# Inefficient jQuery usage warnings in PHPStorm IDE

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance

I recently upgraded my version of PHPStorm IDE and it now warns me about inefficient jQuery usage.

For example:

```
var property_single_location = $("#property [data-role='content'] .container");
```

Prompts this warning:

> Checks that jQuery selectors are used in an efficient way. It suggests
>   to split descendant selectors which are prefaced with ID selector and
>   warns about duplicated selectors which could be cached.

So my question is:

> Why is this inefficient and what is the efficient way to do the above selector?

I'd guess at:

```
var property_single_location = $("#property").find("[data-role='content']").find(".container");
```

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I had the same question today and was able to find a solution thanks to [Scott Kosman](https://twitter.com/humantorch) [**here**](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/).

Basically the answer is to select IDs individually and then use `.find(...)` for anything below. So taking your example:

```
$("#property [data-role='content'] .container");
```

Changing it to this makes PhpStorm happy and can evidently be [more than twice as fast](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/):

```
$("#property").find("[data-role='content'] .container");
```

Comment: For my taste $('[data-role="content"] .container', '#property'); is more readable.

Comment: @n3rd Funny, I don't find that approach readable at all, but to each his own they say.

Answer (score 19):

I believe the difference between the two methods when using recent versions of jQuery and browsers is negligible.  I constructed a test that shows that it is now actually 10% faster to do a combined selector rather than selection on id and then find for a very simple case:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-insel

For selection of multiple children by class at any depth, the "find" does appear to be faster:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-insel/7

There was some discussion about this on jQuery forums, but its 3 years old:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/which-jquery-selection-is-efficient
As they point out here, if you are doing a lot of operations on same id selector, the greatest performance improvement is found by caching the top level element.
On the other hand if you are doing just a few selections, there is going to be virtually no performance difference.

Therefor I believe that IntelliJ is overstating the importance of this code style.

Comment: In your first test, you are using the direct decedent select ">". I ran your first test without ">", and using "find" is faster. http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-insel/12

Comment: The thing I find about this most interesting is that the latest versions of Safari process the direct method fastest by about 25%.  I don't know what they've done, but apparently all the other browsers haven't caught on.

Answer (score 14):

The first question is to hit Alt+Enter, and select the first tip in the list, then hit Enter, you'll see what it thinks the most efficient way.