# improve inefficient jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, if I use a jQuery selector such as:

```
$('#roleField option').each(function() {
    // impl omitted
});
```

The selector is highlighted with a suggestion that I should

> split descendant selectors which are prefaced with ID selector

what exactly is IntelliJ suggesting that I should replace the selector above with?

Comment: I think `$('#roleField').find('option')`

Comment: Not sure if it's what it's referring to or not, but using find for child selectors has been proven to be considerably faster - `$('#roleField').find('option').each()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny why it is suggesting so..? will doing like that improve performance..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inefficient jQuery usage warnings in PHPStorm IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674591/inefficient-jquery-usage-warnings-in-phpstorm-ide)

Comment: Seems like a silly warning. While using .find might improve speed by a couple milliseconds, it's not really worth the sacrifice in easy readability. I personally (have been using jQuery PROFESSIONALLY for 6 years now) don't use `.find` unless it's on an assigned variable. If I have a `selector`, like you show above, I just do exactly what you're doing, `$('#id child')`. There's really no reason to replace it with `$('#id').find('child')`

Comment: I think because if you use id selector alone then jQuery might use `getElementById()` to fetch first record...

Comment: According to http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/2 `find` _does_ speed up the selector :)

Comment: @fboes Not by much. Not enough to be "considerable". Also, this is ID->tag, thus, here, much more simple and direct test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-find2

Comment: Aside from the fact, in today's day and age of GPU's being "standard" for mobile computing, and standards for desktops and laptops being FAR better than they were even 5 years ago ... why are we even arguing JS performance?

Comment: @SpYk3HH Just out of curiosity, how many options are there in the element with the id `roleField`?

Answer (score 19):

From the jquery documentation this method will not go through the Sizzle sector engine:

```
$('#roleField option').each(function() {
    // No Sizzle
});
```

Where this one will:

```
$('#roleField').find('option')  // Sizzle!
```

Look at the ID base selectors section [here](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/#id-based-selectors).  Hence the second method will be faster than the first.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `.find()` here:

```
$('#roleField').find('option').each(function() {
    // impl omitted
});
```

Your warning seem like related to efficiency of the selector.

**[Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674591/inefficient-jquery-usage-warnings-in-phpstorm-ide)**

Comment: Already answered in the comments and the link you posted.  You shouldn't post links as answers - you should use the close button.

Comment: @Archer yes, but he's providing an actual answer. Although, before you go telling people it's "considerably" faster, please post some proof. I've been using child selectors and saving .find for use only on variables for years and never seen any "considerable" difference. In other words, I've never considered it to be much faster and I've tried it both ways in the my early days.

Comment: @Archer Comments are comments, answers are answers and this is `IntelliJ` and not `PHPStorm` and I'm not posting link as an anser as well.

Comment: The link you provided shows the exact same issue with the exact same code change that you have suggested.  You should have pointed this out to the OP with the link.