# Performance css rules vs. jQuery .toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm running a wordpress theme, which has a sticky header. I've built a subnav, which is displayed right below the header. Whenever I use this subnav, the header should not stay sticky, instead the subnav should be sticky (already made with simple javascript addClass). I am only interested how to turn off the stickiness of the header the best way.

(1) Using CSS:
One way is to use css and to override the classes, which make the header sticky. This already works, I've just changed the position fixed to static and disabled the placeholder, which avoids a gap in the content, when the position is set to fixed and the header is taken out of the flow. Based on the circumstance that I want to use the subnav on many pages (ca. 70%) I would have to write one big css rule for targeting the relevant pages by their ids. This leads to my thought that javascript may better on resources.

(2) Using Javascript:
I've wrote a small snippet of javascript, which easily removes the whole css-classes, when the ID of the subnav is present on the page:

```
if(document.getElementById('subnavfullwidth')){
jQuery( '.header-sticky-height' ).toggleClass( 'header-sticky-height', 'false' );
jQuery( '.header-wrapper' ).toggleClass( 'header-is-sticky', 'false' );
jQuery( '.header' ).toggleClass( '.header-sticky-shadow', 'false' );
}
```

Simple as the title: Would the javascript be better or one big css-rule for the site performance? Is there a way to optimize my javascript or is it just okay?

Kind Regards!

Comment: You can optomize the javascript by adding id's to your selectors.  See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518072/improve-inefficient-jquery-selector/23518492#23518492

Comment: Hi terpmind, do I have to add ID's to the css classes above (.header-sticky-height, .header-wrapper & .header) or would it be also possible to use an id of another element. The very parent element of the whole page is #wrap_all. Could I also use this for a better performance? -> jQuery ( '#wrap_all').find('.header-sticky-height).toggleClass and so on?

Comment: Performance should be rather irrelevant here. / From the perspective of readability and maintainability, I would switch/toggle only _one_ class via JS here, for either the body or the html element; everything else I'd keep in the stylesheet, using descendants selectors.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I also had that in mind. Just wanted to get an answer from some professionals about performance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to have one class added to '.header' (assuming that's the root element of the relevant area) named sticky, and change the class header to an id of header.

The way you have it written, you could gain a little performance by adding an id to '.header', and then chain methods together to limit the number of elements to have to search through.

```
$('#header')
    .toggleClass('header-sticky-shadow', false)
    .find('.header-wrapper')
        .toggleClass('header-is-sticky', false)
    .end()
    .find('.header-sticky-height', false)
        .toggleClass('header-sticky-height', false);
```

Comment: Hi dyagmin, your code worked, it will take a little time to test whether there is a real perfomance boost or not ;)