# Difference between `space` and find() in selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to remove all options but the first from my `<select/>`. I understand that `children()` would not work recursively.

Is there any difference between

```
$('#mySelect :gt(0)').remove();
```

and

```
$('#mySelect').find(':gt(0)').remove();
```

?

Comment: in second method you can use `end()` , to get `#mySelect`

Comment: In first method same can be done using `closest`

Comment: Funny sidenote: I switched to phpStorm today. It told me to change it to `.(find)` so it's more efficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674591/inefficient-jquery-usage-warnings-in-phpstorm-ide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shockingly I can't find a duplicate of this question, all the others are about speed.

There's no *significant* difference in the two lines of code you've quoted, no.

Comment: That's it, you can add the comments(from Pranav) text in answer, that's helpful

Comment: ikr!! that's kinda the reason for me asking that, honestly. :p

Comment: Check this https://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/ please read the first section **Selector speed: fast or slow?**

Answer (score 1):

find() method is useful if we already have parent element reference:

```
 var parentElement = $('#mySelect');
    /*
    * there is some code..
    * do some thing on parent
    */
```

Now if we want to get parentElement's children we can use either

`parentElement.find('.xtz');` or `$('.xtz',parentElement)`

rather than using complete selector either

`$('#mySelect .xtz');`  or
`$('#mySelect').find('.xtz');`

Comment: Context selector can also be used in this case, `$('.xyz', parentElement);`