# inefficient jquery usage - multiple selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

My IDE is throwing a unique warning.

the jQuery code is :

```
var $xcol = $("#xcol");
var $ycol = $("#ycol");
var $filtercol = $("#filtercol");

$filtercol.on('change', function(event, params) {
        // can now use params.selected and params.deselected
        var value;
        var text;
        if (params.selected){
            value =  params.selected;
            $("#xcol option[value='"+value+"']").remove();
            $("#ycol option[value='"+value+"']").remove();
            $xcol.trigger("chosen:updated");
            $ycol.trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
        else if (params.deselected){
            value =  params.deselected;
            text = $("#filtercol option[value='"+value+"']").text()
            $xcol.append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ text +'</option>');
            $ycol.append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ text +'</option>');
            $xcol.trigger("chosen:updated");
            $ycol.trigger("chosen:updated");
        }

    });
```

the warning is flagged on this line of code:

```
 $("#xcol option[value='"+value+"']").remove();
```

How can I fix this warning? THANKS!

[image]

Comment: Consider using the `.find()` method against `$filterCol` rather than using the selector. [idea reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16620060/3485669)

Comment: What does the "more..." link tell you?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way is to not add many selectors when leading with an ID:

```
$("#xcol option[value='"+value+"']").remove();
$("#filtercol option[value='"+value+"']").text()
```

to

```
$("#xcol").find("option[value='"+value+"']").remove(); 
$("#filtercol").find("option[value='"+value+"']").text()
```